# Infinite loop in this binary search implementation?

Tags: c, binary-search

Can anyone help me find the error in this implementation of the binary search algorithm. I guess it is running in an infinite loop. There is a problem in function definition but not sure what.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define max 5

int binarysearch(int a[],int element,int first,int last);//prototype

int main(void) 
{
    int arr[max]={1,2,3,7,8};
    int b;
    int start=0;
    scanf("%d",&b);
    int search=binarysearch(arr,b,start,max-1);
    if(search==-1)
    {
        puts("element is not there in array");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("element found at position %d",search);
    }
}

int binarysearch(int a[],int element,int first,int last)//definition
{
    int mid=(first+last)/2;
    int initial;int final;
    while(first<=last)
    {
        if(a[mid]==element)
        {
            return mid;
        }
        else if(a[mid]<element)
        {
            initial=mid+1;
            final=last;
            binarysearch(a,element,initial,final);
        }
        else if(a[mid]>element)
        {
            initial=first;
            final=mid-1;
            binarysearch(a,element,initial,final);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's a home work. Please discuss your question instead of trying to have cooked answer. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unnecessary loop inside the function:

```
while(first<=last)
```

This is an infinite loop, because `first` and `last` are never reassigned inside the loop. You already use recursion by calling `binarysearch` inside the loop body. Either change the `while` to `if`, or remove the recursive calls and assign to `first` and `last` instead of `initial` and `final` (and recalculate `mid` accordingly).

If you decide to stick with the recursive approach, also change the calls to `return binarysearch(…);` or the return value is lost.

Comment: changing while to if gives a run-time error yet gives a correct output but the second way you suggested works.Can you tell why it is so? i tried it on ideone.com

Comment: @novice Which error? Did you add the `return`s? Post a new question with the new code if you have a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make the below changes

```
int binarysearch(int a[],int element,int first,int last)//definition
{
int mid=(first+last)/2;
int initial;int final;

if(first > last)
{
  printf("Not found\n");
  return -1;
}
    if(a[mid]==element)
    {
        return mid;
    }
    else if(a[mid]<element)
    {
        initial=mid+1;
        final=last;
        binarysearch(a,element,initial,final);
    }
    else if(a[mid]>element)
    {
        initial=first;
        final=mid-1;
        binarysearch(a,element,initial,final);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work: the return values of the recursive calls are lost.